# Replace NA values in one dataframe with values from a second

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look like so:

df1:

```
     A    B    C    D   E   F.              EMAIL
1   78   46   65   59  NA  NA. bill@microsoft.com
2   60   51   64   67  NA  NA. bill@microsoft.com
3   72   83   54   72  NA  NA. bill@microsoft.com
```

df2:

```
     A    B    C    D   E   F.              EMAIL
1   NA   NA   NA   NA  71  99. bill@microsoft.com
2   NA   NA   NA   NA  53  74. bill@microsoft.com
```

what I want to end up with is:
df3

```
     A    B    C    D   E   F               EMAIL
1   78   46   65   59  71  99. bill@microsoft.com
2   60   51   64   67  53  74. bill@microsoft.com
3   72   83   54   72  NA  NA. bill@microsoft.com
```

I have tried merge, coalesce, join, rqdatable all with no success.  I am new to R and am running out of ideas on how to make this happen.   How can I replace the values of one dataframe with values from a second?

Thanks!
-g

Comment: To do this reliably (in my experience) there should be either (1) a common "id" field so that rows from one can be tied authoritatively with rows in the other; or (2) certainty that row `n` in one is perfectly tied to row `n` in the other frame.

Comment: The fact that `df1` has 3 and `df2` has 2 rows tells me that ... my #2 is not true, so refer to #1: if you don't have some common unique identifier for each row, then I suggest that your data is not structured in a way that doing this kind of operation is safe or advisable.

Comment: There is a common id, I just omitted it.  I added it back in.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. Is there a unique id per-row in `df1` that ties (for instance) row 1 of `df1` with row 1 of `df2`? Or is it unimportant which order the numbers go in each column? If your output `$E` were `c(53,71,NA)` instead, would it mean something different?

Comment: The order is unimportant in this case.  I just want to grab the first row in second set and merge it with the first row in the first set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i <- seq(nrow(df2))

df1[i,] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x),
               df1[i,], df2)

df1
#    A  B  C  D  E  F
# 1 78 46 65 59 71 99
# 2 60 51 64 67 53 74
# 3 72 83 54 72 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := Map(fcoalesce, .SD, df2[nm1]), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have not tried this but I am going to add this to my notes.  This would be useful for some other things I am working on.